# Performance_Python get union of 2 lists of tuple according to 2 out of the 3 elements of the tuple

Tags: python, list, union, tuples

My program is not doing a great job. In a loop, data from each processor (list of tuple) are gathered into the master processor that needs to clean it by removing similar element.

I found a lot of interesting clue on internet and especially in this site about union of list. However, i have not managed to apply it to my problem. 
My aim is to get rid of tuple whose its two last element are similar to another tuple in the list . for example:

```
list1=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
list2=[[b,b,c],[d,e,a],[k,h,i]]
the result should be:
final=[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i],[d,e,a]]
```

Right now I'm using loops and break but I'm hoping to make this process faster.

here is what my code looks like (result and temp are the lists I want to get union from)
on python2.6.

```
for k in xrange(len(temp)):
    u=0
    #index= next((j for j in xrange(lenres) if temp[k][1:3] == result[j][1:3]),None)
    for j in xrange(len(result)):
        if temp[k][1:3] == result[j][1:3]:
            u=1
            break
    if u==0:
    #if index is None:
        result.append([temp[k][0],temp[k][1],temp[k][2]])
```

Thanks for your help

Herve

Comment: By the way, lists `[...]` are not tuples `(...)` and performance may differ between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is our uniques function.  It takes arguments l (list) and f (function), returns list with duplicates removed (in the same order).  Duplicates are defined by: b is duplicate of a iff f(b) == f(a).

```
def uniques(l, f = lambda x: x):
    return [x for i, x in enumerate(l) if f(x) not in [f(y) for y in l[:i]]]
```

We define lastTwo as follows:

```
lastTwo = lambda x: x[-2:]
```

For your problem we use it as follows:

```
>>> list1
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i')]
>>> list2
[('b', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'a'), ('k', 'h', 'i')]
>>> uniques(list1+list2, lastTwo)
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('d', 'e', 'a')]
```

If the usecase you describe comes up a lot you may want to define

```
def hervesMerge(l1, l2):
    return uniques(l1+l2, lambda x: x[-2:])
```

Identity is our default f but it can be anything (so long as it is defined for all elements of the list, since they can be of any type).

f can be sum of a list, odd elements of a list, prime factors of an integer, anything.  (Just remember that if its injective theres no point!  Add by constant, linear functions, etc will work no differently than identity bc its f(x) == f(y) w/ x != y that makes the difference)

```
>>> list1
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 5), (6, 2, 2), (3, 4), (8, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
>>> uniques(list1, sum)
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 5), (8, 3)]
>>> uniques(list1, lambda x: reduce(operator.mul, x))  #product
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
>>> uniques([1,2,3,4,1,2]) #defaults to identity
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You seemed concerned about speed, but my answer really focused on shortness/flexibility without significant (or any?) speed improvment.  For bigger lists where speed is z concern, you want to take advantage of hashable checks and the fact that list1 and list2 are known to have no duplicates

```
>>> s = frozenset(i[-2:] for i in list1)
>>> ans = list(list1) #copy list1
>>> for i in list2:
        if i[-2:] not in s: ans.append(i)
>>> ans
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('d', 'e', 'a')]
```

OR allowing disordering

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> for i in list2 + list1:
        d[i[-2:]] = i
>>> d.values()
[('d', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('d', 'e', 'a')]
```

--Edit--

You should always be able to avoid un-pythonic looping like you post in your question.  Here is your exact code with the loops changed:

```
for k in temp:
  u=0
  for j in result:
      if k[1:3] == j[1:3]:
          u=1
          break
  if u==0:
  #if index is None:
      result.append([k[0],k[1],k[2]])   // k
```

result and temp are iterable, and for anything iterable you can put it directly in the for loop without eanges.  If for some reason you explicitly need the index (this is not such a case, but I have one above) you can use enumerate.

Comment: sorry if i got carried away.  i liked your question and kind of turned it into a project of my own =P

Comment: Thank you!. Using lambda was what I had in mind, but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: glad you likw.  i posted a different solution focusing on your exact problem for speed, being thats what you asked about.    you should accept one of the answers.  besides hooking up the person you accept, this will make people more likely to answer you in the future.  also will earn you a pretty badge

Comment: Thanks again. This is very neat. I did not know about the all accept answer thing. It took me a while but i think i manage to accept your answer by clicking on the check beside your answer. It seems that I can only accept one answer...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using a set:

```
list1=[('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),('g','h','i')]
list2=[('b','b','c'),('d','e','a'),('k','h','i')]

set1 = set([A[1:3] for A in list1])
final = list1 + [A for A in list2 if A[1:3] not in set1]
```

However, if your list1 and list2 aren't actually made of tuples, then you will have to put tuple() around A[1:3].

Comment: Are you sure? `final` ends being almost exactly what you have listed as the desired result. How is it not working?

Comment: My apologize...  For some reason, when I copied your code onto my python shell I was getting error messages. After reading your message I just tried again and as you said it does work. Sorry and Thank you